# How do you calculate required uplink on a Switch?

Tags: switch, bandwidth, uplinks

Lets just say i have an access switch with 8 1G port downlink, and all downlink ports are connected to the users. I want to connect said switch to an aggregation switch.

How do I determine the bandwidth needed for the uplink?
Do I need 8x1G= 8G uplink which means a 10G port?

Comment: You may find [this question about over subscription](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/60002/16930) and the comment by @RonMaupin on the question worth reading.

Comment: If your question is "is a switch with *N* 1G ports **required** to be connected to >*N*Gbps uplink to function", then the answer is no.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is "oversubscription" in Networking?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/60002/what-is-oversubscription-in-networking)

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on your workloads.

If you've got eight **"light" users** that work with some office documents, surf the 'net, send and receive a few emails, oversubscription is a non-issue. It might not even matter if the users are connected by gigabit or only 100 Mbit/s. You could even have 40 end nodes or more on a single gigabit uplink without any problem.

If you've got eight **servers** that are moderately-to-seriously frequented, or **heavy users** (moving large data amounts, video, ...) you'd want to make sure that there are no bottlenecks. Server backup may also run out of its window, so you'd need at least 2-4 Gbit/s uplink, the more the better.

In extreme, you've got a **backup repository cluster** where you'd want no potential bottleneck *at all* - that'd mean a 10 Gbit/s uplink (or for that matter, dedicated 10 Gbit/s to each node, 40+ Gbit/s uplink).

To better size your workloads it really helps to monitor the current links for a while. Ideally, you track daily traffic amount and height and width/length of the peaks. At least try to grab (or write down) the port counters once or twice a day.

Answer (score 0):

The correct thing would be to monitor this switch, so you would know how much these users consume today.
 
If you think about expanding this network in this location, I believe that you should think about a switch with SFP+, at first you can use the 1Gbps Ethernet port, if necessary change to SFP+, that way the equipment will serve you for a good time.

Think about how much your network will grow, and how long you want to keep this equipment, good luck! ;P

Answer (score 0):

It's all depends upon your bandwidth utlization and traffic and number of end users connected on access -layer switch it's . With help of Port channel and link aggrigation you can bind 8 uplinks from distribution to access switch or from core switch to access switch ..